# How to schedule IOS UserNotification by excluding today

Tags: ios, swift, notifications

i would like to send a notification to my iOS application users just a day following the registration of the notification. In other words, i want to exclude the day of the registration of the notification in the UNUserNotificationCenter (I want to send the notification everyday from tomorrow on).

```
    var dateInfo = DateComponents()
    dateInfo.hour = 12
    dateInfo.minute = 30
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = NSString.localizedUserNotificationString(forKey: "daily notification:", arguments: nil)
    content.body = NSString.localizedUserNotificationString(forKey: "Hello ！Get up,", arguments: nil)
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()
    content.badge = UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber + 1 as NSNumber;
    content.categoryIdentifier = "Daily notification"
    // Deliver the notification every day at 12:30 am.
    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateInfo, repeats: false)
    let request = UNNotificationRequest.init(identifier: "midnoonHalfNotification", content: content, trigger: trigger)
```

Comment: I want to do the same thing, did you solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the time interval between now (when the request is created) and 12:30 tomorrow and use a UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger as the trigger with the calculated interval instead of the calendar trigger.